# Is this true that the Soviet Army soldiers had no helmets in the beginning of WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union

Is this true that the Soviet Army was so poorly equipped by the WW2 that soldiers had no helmets?

Comment: I looked up some photos of dead Russian soldiers from the Barbarossa campaign and they usually had helmets on the ground next to them. I would not sweat it though, helmets are overrated, just makes you a better target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know about helmets specifically, but in a nutshell, no. The Red Army was very well equipped; it had more airplanes and tanks (and some of them of better make) than the Germans. Same goes for many other categories of materiel.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Barbarossa) gives this table for June 22, 1941:

> ```
>                Germany and allies     Soviet Union
> ```
>
> Divisions                           166                            190
>
> Personnel                    4,306,800                  3,289,851
>
> Guns and mortars           42,601                      59,787
>
> Tanks                              4,171                               15,687
>
> Aircraft                            4,389                        11,537

Comment: It was called "Red Army" at the time.

Comment: http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/material_materiel.htm :)

Answer (score 8):

I am surprised that nobody linked to suitable wikipedia page:

[Soviet helmets during World War II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_helmets_during_World_War_II)

Quote from article:

> The SSh (stalnoy shlem, or steel helmet) 39 was of simple, more modern design, and was much easier to manufacture than the M36. The SSh-39 would be the standard design for Soviet helmets for the next 29 years, with only minor changes occurring during that time. It is also the design for the helmet on the Tomb of the Unknown Soldier in Moscow. The helmet was produced primarily in three factories, the Stalingrad Tractor Factory (designated CT in the ink stamp), the Red October Factory (3K0) also in Stalingrad, and the Lysva Metallurgical Factory (LMZ).[2] The first liner was an eight-finger leather liner, similar to the German M35-M42. Next came a short production of an eight-finger liner made of Gralex. The final version of the SSh-39 liner was cloth, similar to the M-36 liner. All three variations of the liner were suspended from the helmet by three metal tabs, which were riveted to the shell near the top. This helmet, like the M-36, saw action in numerous campaigns before it was phased out in 1942 in favor of the SSh-40.

Article also mentions other 2 types of helmets used in World War II (`M-36` and `SSh-40`) and `Adrian helmet` that was used in early years of Soviet Union. Also there's a poster with classic red star helmet:

[image]

So, the answer is no. It's a myth.

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Comment: except it doesn't take into consideration things like scarcity and production numbers. Since 2 of the factories were in Stalingrad, I'd expect scarcity due to loss of those factories from 1942 on to the point new factories could be opened and start mass production elsewhere. And without sufficient stockpiles, early during mobilisation there might indeed have been troops without access to helmets.

Comment: @jwenting Nice point. I was answering OP's question: `soviet army soldiers had no helmets`. My point is that regular army was equipped with helmets in 1941. I'll try to find sources on production numbers. If you have references on helmet shortage during mass mobilization be sure to post them here.

Comment: @defaultlocale I've heard a lot about Soviet troops arriving at Stalingrad and being sent into the line with 1 rifle for every 2-3 of them. Wouldn't surprise me at all if the same were true of other items of basic equipment.

Comment: @jwenting I hope you understand that [Enemy at the Gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_at_the_Gates) is not really historically accurate movie? I think that you need *really strong* evidence to support claims like that.

Comment: @defaultlocale no, it's not completely accurate. But it's not that farfetched either seeing the speed at which the Soviets were pouring in troops, often raw recruits, and the losses the supply train was facing under German (mostly Luftwaffe) bombardment. Remember the movie is based on fact, if embellished both because it's based on a Soviet propaganda campaign (which would never mention troops being sent into combat without weapons), the personal recollection of survivors, and dramatic necessity. I doubt a soldier would forget being sent into battle without a rifle...

Comment: @jwenting `movie is based on fact` great assumption, I can't wait to see answers on stackoverflow and programmers.SE based on [Swordfish](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244244). `the personal recollection of survivors` Again if you can link to any kind of such memoirs (soviet soldier fighting against Germans with bare hands) feel free to post it. This discussion went too far without any factual evidence.

Comment: Possibly you could improve the answer by pointing that the helmet on the picture is not the typical for WWII SSh-40 but the Adrian helmet which was mostly obsolete by the time.

Answer (score 4):

The myth of Russian helmets is quite popular speaking not only about the beginning of the war. The truth is that even if Soviet Army had enough helmets, there were some other reasons why soldiers didn't want to use them.

First of all, they were highly uncomfortable and reduced the sight, so soldiers preferred caps. Also they were made of very poor material (don't ask me for details) and too weak to provide good cover from anything (not speaking of bullets, as there were no helmets at those times which could protect from a shot). This way especially at the end of the war, when Germans didn't have as much artillery, helmets weren't so important for Russian soldiers. Another reason I've heard about was the shiny material, which helped Germans shooters to localize Soviet soldiers from a distance.

In the queue to blame there's also Russian propaganda machine. It's said that when Soviet Army were coming to Poland, soldiers heard from everywhere that Germans are in panic and they just run away from Poland leaving everything, including helmets. This way some Russian soldiers diaries contain scenes of leaving heavy and uncomfortable helmets on the road, in order to get a new one, left by Germans. They didn't even expect to fight until they reach the German border and in many cases they were right about it. Sounds a bit like Catch 22, don't you think?

Comment: I wish you would've provided some sources.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't quite get your last paragraph. Do you mean to say that Russian propaganda machine would disseminate the message that Russian soldiers had helmets of poor quality (as compared to those of Germans) and that they didn't want to fight before reaching the German border? Why would Russian propaganda machine spread some bad things about Russian army?

Comment: Of course, taking a German helmlet instead of Soviet one would be punishable. A soldier has to keep his equipment and has to wear standard uniform. Not to say that in German helmlet he could be accidentally taken for an enemy. It is possible that they collected German (or other foreign) helmlets and re-furbished, re-painted them, but I never heared about such enterprise. At the same time Germans wearing Soviet refurbished helmlets were not uncommon.

Comment: @brilliant Soviet propaganda loved showing the heroic Soviet soldier. Showing him without a helmet, hair streaming in the wind, standing on top of a destroyed German tank or the ruins of a bunker made for great propaganda.

Comment: @Anixx it's easy to "lose" a helmet or other gear. And taking a looted replacement from a fallen enemy is standard practice. This includes helmets, belts, weapons, everything that's of higher quality than what you were issued yourself. This goes on to this day, and has always been done throughout history. Of course today, there's not much of quality to loot from a shot taliban guerilla except maybe a dagger as a souvenir, but in WW2 many Americans e.g. ended up with German weapons which were superior to their own.

Comment: With propaganda, I meant the following situation. Imagine that you hear from everywhere something like "Those bloody Germans are running away! They are so scarred of us, brave Soviets, that they even leave their weapon and helmets!". So the Soviet soldiers didn't even expect to fight at all until the border of Germany, which would be more important for Germans than "just Poland". Of course after the propaganda machine did something completely opposite - they rewritten the history claiming that there were so heavy fights for Polish towns and making Soviet generals heroes of liberation.

Comment: Unfortunately with sources they're mainly "I've asked my grandpa" kind of stories. It's just a common knowledge of the old generation who were still young at those times, but I can try to find some valuable sources in Polish language.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski- I am sorry to say that, but it seems that you being Polish naturally are giving some biased answers here. I need sources, valid and credible ones.

Comment: @brilliant the Poles have little reason to love either Germans or Soviets, don't think that would cause bias in his answer :)

Comment: @jwenting - Unfortunately, my experience of interaction with the Polish shows completely a different situation. However, I agree with you that Poles don't like Germans. It also known yet that when Poles are given to choose between Russia or Germany, they would undoubtedly choose Germany, which is understood.

Comment: I can understand your opinion about Poles and of course I understand that you need more valuable sources. With love and hate it depends, as pretty much everywhere in the world. But there's a joke that's popular among tourist guides, I'll write it in the next comment. Of course don't treat it seriously.

Comment: So imagine you're a Polish soldier and there are German and Russian soldiers that try to attack you. The question - which one should you kill in the first order? The answer - first German and then Russian. Because first there comes a duty, and after that, the pleasure.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski and the Russian is more likely to have the same dilemma and shoot at the German too, giving you valuable time to switch targets :)

Comment: I can't remember where I read it, but I've read that Red Army soldiers were a bit surprised that Americans wore their helmets everywhere. They themselves thought that helmets were more suitable for defensive battles, but were too heavy and cumbersome when attacking. Obviously this wouldn't have been a universal attitude, and there are plenty of pics of RA soldiers in helmets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mistaken with the wars. This is true for the Great War. Russian forces were poorly equipped and helmets were the last thing Russian industry would have thought of.

[Here](http://www.artelista.com/en/great-masters/artwork/3317354558087111-russian-infantry-charging-during-brusilovs-offensive-against-austria-hungary-world-war-i-1916.html) is a picture of charging Russian infantry in 1916 (I do not put it here due to copyright).

Comment: Steel Helmets where not in use at all for infantry at the start of WWI for any army.  Even those helmets with the spike for Germans were leather.  They were adopted later in the war by all armies.